# How can I create a simple 4x3 two dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, system.out

I've got it down in C++, but Java is proving more challenging to me. Here's what i have. I simply want it to have 4 rows and 3 columns initialized to 1-12 and to print it to the screen. Are my errors apparent to you? Thanks!

I get 13 errors :(

> including line9:twoDArray[][] not a statement, ; expected, illegal
>   start of expression, all a few times each.

Code i tried:

```
import java.util.*;


class twoDimensional array
{ public static void main(String args[])
{
int[][] twoDArray = new int[4][3];

twoDArray[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};

System.out.print(twoDArray.toString);


}
}
```

Comment: Pl add your original post and for this splitting please create separate question.

Comment: I would but I deleted the original context. I won't again, sorry.

Comment: I added back original question text, pl accept edit and create another question.

Comment: I did a rollback to the previous version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, arrays (even 2d arrays) don't override `Object.toString`. You can use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) and initialize your array when you declare it. Something like

```
int[][] twoDArray = new int[][] { 
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } 
};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDArray));
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Arrays.deepToString() huh.. I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

Have modified your code

```
import java.util.*;

class twoDimensional array
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]){
      int[][] twoDArray = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};
      //For printing array you have to do 
      System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(twoDArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch buddy!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

class twoDimensionalArray
{ 
public static void main(String args[])
{
int[][] twoDArray = new int[][] { 
    { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } 
};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDArray));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Arrays.deepToString() huh.. I learned something new! Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Here Is The Full Working Copy**

```
public class TwoD {

public static void main(String... args)
{
    int [][]twoD = new int[4][3];
    int num = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            twoD[i][j] = num;
            num++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! Could you help me out with it now that I've edited my question?

Comment: yes because array initialization is not allowed in that case